# Rails - Getting collection of 2-level-relation unique items

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

If I have this relationships stablished

```
class article
    has_many :products
end

class product
    has_one :item
end
```

Given a certain article instance, how could I get a collection (I do not mind if it is an **Array** or an **ActiveRecord_AssociationRelation**) of all the **Items** contained in it, without any repeating? That is every **Item** of the collection being unique.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to get the answer is by flipping the question. Rather than starting from Article and finding all the Items it contains, you can start from Items and select only those contained in the right Article:

```
my_article = Article.find(...)
items = Item.joins(:product).where(product: { article: my_article })
```

This will get you only items which belong to a product which belongs to the article in question.

The list will be unique because you're starting with all Items and then narrowing down the list using `where`.

**Edit:** this assumes that Item has a `belongs_to :product` statement and Product has `belongs_to :article`.

Comment: Of course that would be easier... the problem is that I cant know beforehand what items are contained in the article :) It is always very easy to solve a problem, when you start off with the solution :D

Comment: Sorry, not sure I understand!  All you need to know is the article (`my_article` in the code above).  After running that code, `items` will be filled with the results you're looking for: all of the Items contained in that article.

Comment: It was me who did not understood your answer. It actually works, even though I am not sure it is the most efficient. I will give it a go. Thanks!